# How to change GUID of entity before saving back to database (in C#)

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, deserialization

We have code to serialize entities to file:

```
formatter.Serialize(fileStream, session); // BinaryFormatter
```

and to deserialize:

```
session = (Session)binaryFormatter.Deserialize(innerStream);
```

The entity structure is quite complicated and if necessary I can come up with a simpler example, however the crux of the problem is this.  There is a Patient table that has multiple "Sessions".  The Patient has an associated table "Cities", and therein lies the problems.  Each computer has it's own Database (SQLServer Express) and has a table Cities which contain exactly the same data (London, Madrid, Berlin).  However, on each machine, the unique key for the city (a GUID) is different!  When I deserialize a session on another machine from which it was serialized on, I want to use the same city based on name, NOT Guid.
The deserialization works fine.  It's the deserialized entity to the database that causes me grief.  To get the City GUID correct, I use:

```
session.Patient.City.CityGUID = tempCity.CityGUID;
session.Patient.CityGUID = tempCity.CityGUID;
```

tempCity is the entity from the database with the matching name (like 'London').

I can do this, but on the line:

```
context.Patients.Attach(session.Patient);
```

I get an exception of the form:

```
[System.InvalidOperationException] = {System.InvalidOperationException: The property 'CityGUID' is part of the object's key information and cannot be modified. 
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.EntityEntry.DetectChangesInProperty(Int32 ordinal, Boolean detectOnlyComplexProperties, Boolea...
```

Any ideas on how to fix this?  I can create whole new objects but this is problematic because if I deserialize two sessions that both have the same patient, they should remain that way in the new database.  My creating new entities, I end up with 2 new patients.

I think the best solution is to make sure the Cities have the same GUIDs on different machines, perhaps by modifying the install set, but I'm wondering if there is a simple fix.

Opinions?

Dave

Comment: Is `Patient` a deserialized object too? By the way, what is `session.Patient.Cities`? Looks like a collection, how can it have a guid?

Comment: Thanks for reading my question Gert.  Yes, Patient is a deserialized object too.  A Patient has one or more Sessions.  A Patient is associated with 1 and only 1 city.  And, in an attempt to obfuscate proprietary info, I made a typo.  It should indeed read session.Patient.City.  I'm editing question to fix it. Thanks

Comment: Looks like you can simply remove the `City` objects from the object graph. Setting `session.Patient.CityGUID` is enough to establish the association.

Comment: In fact, I need to replace the entire entity:    session.Patient.City = tempCity;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact, I need to replace the entire entity: session.Patient.City = tempCity;